# Why the comparison results are not the same?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

This is a function on QML. It is not clear why the comparison results differ?

```
...
function someFunction() {
        var id1 = AAAAA.objectId // it is QByteArray property of C++ object
        var id2 = BBBBB.objectId // it is QByteArray property of C++ object
        var isEqual = id1 === id2
        var isEqualToString = id1.toString() === id2.toString()

        console.log("=============================")
        console.log("id1: ", id1)
        console.log("id2: ", id2)
        console.log("isEqual: ", isEqual)
        console.log("id1.toString(): ", id1.toString())
        console.log("id2.toString(): ", id2.toString())
        console.log("isEqualToString: ", isEqualToString)
}
...
```

console result:

```
id1:  2607d35d-d9d0-49af-b944-3fc60993890a
id2:  2607d35d-d9d0-49af-b944-3fc60993890a
isEqual:  false
id1.toString():  2607d35d-d9d0-49af-b944-3fc60993890a
id2.toString():  2607d35d-d9d0-49af-b944-3fc60993890a
isEqualToString:  true
```

Comment: What are the types of `id1` and `id2`? Note that QByteArray does not get automatically mapped to a JS type (see [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html)). Could be that the first comparison happens between unrelated objects, and thus fails.

Comment: As I know there is no conversion from `QByteArray` to some QML/Js type. So it would be comparation between 2 QObject and in this case AAAAA and BBBBB are really different objects. I mean then there are 2 different objects in the memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`id1` and `id2` are javascript `object`:

```
console.log("typeof id1: ", typeof id1)
console.log("typeof id2: ", typeof id2)
```

outputs:

```
qml: typeof id1:  object
qml: typeof id2:  object
```

In javascript, 2 variables of type `object` are equals if and only if they represent the same object. (In C++ it would be like comparing pointers, they are equals if they point to the same address).

Knowing this we can take another look at your code:

```
var id1 = AAAAA.objectId // Creates an object and reference it by id1
var id2 = BBBBB.objectId // Creates of another object and reference it by id2
var isEqual = id1 === id2 // false because id1 and id2 reference 2 different objects, regardless of their content
var isEqualToString = id1.toString() === id2.toString() // true because you compare strings and strings are compared using their content
```